# Line graph, grouped lines instead of single line

Tags: r

I have used the following code to create a line graph.

```
NewZealandDataPop <- covid19_population %>% 
  filter(`Country/Region` %in% "New Zealand")
NewZealandDataPop


ggplot(data = NewZealandDataPop, aes(x = date, y = cases/pop2020, colour = Status)) + geom_line() + labs(x="Month(2020)", y = "Number of Cases")
```

However, the graph shows like this:

[image]

Is there any obvious reason why my lines show like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your data?  Can you show us (some of) your data?  You code looks OK, so I suspect it's a problem with your input.  Perhaps you have some zeros in cases?

Certainly, this code gives the format I think you're looking for.

````
d <- tibble(
       Status=rep(1:3, each=50), 
       X=rep(1:50, times=3), 
       Z=exp(3 + Status*log(X/25)), 
       Y=Z/(1+Z))
> d %>% ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=as.factor(Status))) + geom_line()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you restart your R and double check both your data and code. Without your data, I cannot reproduce you graph with your code. With a different dataset with different values, I ran your code:

```
pop2020<-4822.233
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(date), 
           y = cases/pop2020, 
           colour = Status)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x="Month(2020)", y = "Number of Cases")
```

I used `as.Date(date)` in my data, but should not generate your graph otherwise. With your code, I got:

[image]